# Explicit form of the homeomorphism between $C[0,1]$ and $C[0,1]\setminus 0$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

How to construct the homeomorphism between $C[0,1]$ and $C[0,1]\setminus\{\theta\}$
in the explicit form?

Here, as usual, $C[0,1]$ is the Banach space of continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ with the norm
$$
\|f\|=\max\limits_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|;
$$
and $\theta(x)\equiv 0$ $\forall x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: This does not appear to be a homework question unless I am missing something.

Comment: I would try to adapt the construction for $\ell_2$ to $c_0$ and use the fact that $c_0$ is isometric to a norm one complemented subspace of $C[0,1])$ in a natural way.

Comment: [same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421393/explicit-form-of-the-homeomorphism-between-c0-1-and-c0-1-setminus-0) on MSE with helpful comment by Martin